# MySQL mysqldump.exe is only backing up schemes

Tags: backup, mysql

I have this command which is only creating statements to re-create the database and schemes, but it's not backing up any of the data:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.0.6\mysqldump.exe" --user=myuser --password=mypassword  --host=localhost --port=3306 --result-file="Z:\mysql-backup\backup.%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%.sql" --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --databases "wpzb" "wptt"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the basic command:

```
mysqldump -u myuser -pmypassword --databases wpzb watt > dump_file.sql
```

You should get all the data and schema in one file

It might be best to execute the command for each database separately:

```
mysqldump -u myuser -pmypassword --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE  wpzb > wpzb_dump_file.sql
```

This way you have the schema and data for one database in one file!

Since the database is local and on the default port you can just use:

```
-u myuser -pmypassword
```

And leave the localhost and port attributes off.

I tested with no-data=true in the my.ini file on Windows and running mysqldump now dumps no data.

my.ini

```
[client]
no-data=true
```

Comment: Thanks, but I fail to see how that's different from what I have. Also, how would I include the current datetime and set target folder for the resulting file?

Comment: --result-file should work like you have it and I tested it and it work for me. Have you checked to see if there is a config file with --no-data option set, it is possible that mysqldump is reading a config file.

Answer (score 0):

```
backup: # mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```